# How do you separate results by a character when looping through an XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, email

I am storing some settings in a settings.xml file for my C# Windows Forms Application and in that XML file I am storing e-mail addresses.

I would ultimately like to achieve being able to loop through these e-mail addresses and send one e-mail to all of them.

What would be the best way of looping through them and adding them using the To.Add method of the MailMessage class in C#?

I already have the following code below to retrieve them from the XML file:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "//settings.xml");
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XElement c in doc.Descendants("EmailAddresses")) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Results: " + c.Value, "Test");
}
```

I have not been able to figure out how to split the results. The results in the MessageBox are like so: `"email@domain.comemail@domain.comemail@domain.com"` and so on..or even if this is the best way to achieve what I want.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: why don't you add them to a List<T>.. can you show what the actual content / structure of the xml file looks like for the EmailAddresses also why don't you consider storing the email addresses in a database or a text file with a delimiter so that you can split it out later into a List<>

Comment: Make an Email Address node; you shouldn't need to parse out the data if you control the format.  Like a database - make each field atomic.

Comment: May be `MessageBox.Show("Results: " + c.Value+" ", "Test");`

Comment: My XML file looks like so:

<settings>
  <EmailAddresses>
    <Email1>test@test.com</Email1>
    <Email2>test2@test.com</Email2>
    <Email3>test3@test.com</Email3>
  </EmailAddresses>
</settings>

I have been thinking to store them in a Microsoft SQL database table...how could I approach it then if I do that?

Comment: @user3620761: `XElement.Parse(xml_text).Descendants("EmailAddresses").DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text).ToList();` would provide you the list of 3 emails.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than evaluating the entire content below the "EmailAddresses" element, you should be enumerating its child nodes individually. Assuming the "Email<#>" elements are the only children, code similar to what commenter stribizhev offered should work fine:

```
foreach(XElement c in doc.Descendants("EmailAddresses")
    .SelectMany(x => x.DescendantNodes()
        .Where(‌​x => x.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Results: " + c.Value, "Test");
}
```

Note that you can't actually call `DescendantNodes()` on the result of the call to `Descendants()`, as that return value is an instance of `IEnumerable<XElement>`, not a single `XElement`. But you can use the `SelectMany()` method to flatten the enumeration of descendants into an enumeration of *their* descendants.

Alternatively, you could check the node's name:

```
foreach(XElement c in doc.Descendants("EmailAddresses")
    .SelectMany(x => x.Elements().Where(‌​x => x.Name.StartsWith("Email")))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Results: " + c.Value, "Test");
}
```

Based on the information you've provided so far, I would expect either of those to work fine.

The above just displays the values in the `MessageBox`, as in your original example. Obviously, you can just pass `c.Value` to the `MailAddressCollection.Add()` method instead, to add them as you wanted.